# Inconsistent memory layout of c++ struct in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, pack

I have a problem executing c++ code compiled (and debugged) through XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b) on an iPhone simulator.

Code snippet is as below; all the involved files are part of the same library that is later linked to an iPhone application for execution. Please note that the posted code snipped has been customized and trimmed down for investigation purposes, originally it was serving a different purpose, but it has been enough of a pain to isolate the 'offending lines' -.-

```
// HEADER FILE struct_definition.h CONTAINING STRUCT DECLARATION
struct SRowLogBookDescriptor
{
    SRowLogBookDescriptor();

    mutable         u32 key             ;
    std::string     name                ;
    std::string     ui_name             ;
    u32             type                ;
    u32             physical_quantity   ;
    std::string     unit_of_measure     ;
    u32             constraints_size    ;
    u8*             constraints         ;
    std::string     comment             ;
    u64             marker;
};
//---------------------------------------------


// SOURCE FILE struct_definition.cpp CONTAINING STRUCT CONSTRUCTOR DEFINITION
SRowLogBookDescriptor::SRowLogBookDescriptor()
    : key(0xFFFFFFFF)
    , name("name")
    , ui_name("ui_name")
    , type(0xAAAAAAAA)
    , physical_quantity(0x55555555)
    , unit_of_measure("unit")
    , constraints_size(0xB5006BB1)
    , constraints(nullptr)
    , comment("comment")
    , marker(0xBAD00DABBAD00DAB)
{}
//---------------------------------------------


// SOURCE FILE function_call.cpp USING THE MISALIGNED STRUCTURE
void CDefaultLogbookSet::AddDoubleLogBookToSet()
{

    SRowLogBookDescriptor descr;

    int i1 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,key)         ;
    int i2 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,name)                ;
    int i3 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,ui_name)             ;
    int i4 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,type)                ;
    int i5 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,physical_quantity)   ;
    int i6 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,unit_of_measure)     ;
    int i7 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,constraints_size)    ;
    int i8 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,constraints)         ;
    int i9 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,comment)             ;
    int i10 = offsetof(SRowLogBookDescriptor,marker);

    size_t test1 = descr.name.capacity();
    size_t test2 = descr.ui_name.capacity();

    descr.comment = "";
    descr.name = "new_name";
    descr.physical_quantity = 0xaa;
    descr.type = 0x55;
    descr.ui_name = "new_ui_name";
    descr.unit_of_measure = "new_unit";

}
//---------------------------------------------
```

I have a struct which contains 32bits integers, strings, and a pointer. I am well aware that the alignment layout of the struct would lead to wasted bytes due to padding. I have instrumented the constructor of the struct in order to highlight where each field is being mapped into memory.

The struct is then laid on the stack in the *AddDoubleLogBookToSet* function, I save all the offsets for the fields in the struct, I checkout string capacity, filled in with values, then function exits.

As soon as I try to assign a value to the *name* field, I get a **BAD_ACCESS** exception. I am attaching 2 screenshots taken from the XCode debugger when I actually got the exception.
[image: ExceptionInCode]
[image: MemoryLayout]
There you can see the expected offsets for struct attributes, as well as you can see that the debugger actually accesses the attributes at a memory location where they are actually not stored.

I just checked with the debugger that when I execute the constructor the debugger 'sees' the struct members appropriately (I havent attached a screenshot for this).

Now... it appears to me that there is some sort of compilation difference between function_call.cpp and struct_definition.cpp in terms of packing and/or alignement.
I have checked multiple times that each pragma pack in the code is appropriately cleared everytime, and apparently reviewing the code, all is ok.

Let me add that the same c++ code being compiled in Xcode is being compiled and executed smoothly on different Windows releases(PCs) compiled through Visual Studio 2017.
The investigation started because of a wide array of different crashes all related to the library containing the offending code (there are several different structs in that library).
Last but not least, the iPhone application has been executing fine for a long time, then a couple fo weeks ago it stopped executing correctly.

and here is the question: can someone help me out in identifying WHY the 2 source files are being compiled differently?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: clean and rebuild - money says that something didn't get re-compiled correctly

Comment: Perchance, did `desc` come from a *reference* argument to a function, and dynamic allocation from the *caller* of that function, and said allocation naively allocate using C-semantics? Worse, was this structure naively streamed as a blob out of some file or memory backed buffer as a lay-over ? As soon as you said, "pragma pack" with a C++ structure with non-trivial members giant red flags went up. If you're byte-reading this as a blob out of a stream, *bad idea*.

Comment: @UKMonkey - Clean and rebuild has been performed countless times, including deletion of all DerivedData for Xcode.

Comment: @WhozCraig - (as per the posted code) struct instance is created as a simple variable on the stack of normal function without parameters. This triggers the call of the coded default constructor. This structure is not streamed by anything. The structure above IS NOT supposed to be packed, other structures are streamed and packed, but these ones are not, since we usually stay very far away from those red flags that you mention ;) For unknown reasons, we are banging our heads on those red flags, but we cant realize who planted those flags in our source files :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found where the problem was located.

I created a new source file exactly equal to the offending one, further trimmed down its content in order to ease the investigation. I compiled the file and started creating instances of the class pruning code where it was causing the problem versus not causing the problem.

It ended up that there was a 'remote header' file, where packed structures were declared, that had include directives INSIDE the pragma pack(s). Taking those include away from special packing, made the compilation consinstent again across all the files. The include tree was particularly harmful in the Xcode compilation process, compared with the Visual Studio compilation process.

Took only a few days to find out -.-'

Comment: Can you possibly provide more detail on what you were seeing?  I'm struggling with this same issue for way too long!  I don't know what you mean by 'include directives INSIDE the pragma pack(s).  I added ```#pragma pack (show)``` to the two files where the offsets are different and both are showing 4 as the alignment.  So I don't think its a case of the classes having different pack alignments.  Really appreciate any help!

Comment: @DaveHaupert Unfortunately I cannot 'provide more detail on what I am seeing', because the issue dates back more than a year and it was solved. In my case, the alignement problem was not related strictly to the specific struct being defined, but rather because, in one of the files in the include tree, when pragma pack was set at 1, there was a #include <vector> directive, which led to the application of 1-pack of several STL structures. I suggest following a long investigation process, removing code and includes one step at a time, to pinpoint what leads to the issue.